# how to move marker in android step by step from source to destination

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have problem with marker.
I want to move my marker from source to destination.
I have calculated steps to go through coordinates.
I tried to make counter down during each step,but i failed.
My following code :

```
  if (direction.isOK()) {
    // Do something

    //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "we here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
    Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);
//steps here
    step = leg.getStepList();

    final ArrayList<LatLng> sectionList = leg.getDirectionPoint();

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
    int i = 0;
    //go from first point to end point.
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    if(i < step.size()) {

    start = new LatLng(step.get(i).getStartLocation().getLatitude(),step.get(i).getStartLocation().getLongitude());
    //set marker at new position
    marker.setPosition(start);
    i++;

    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
    }.start();
```

I appreciate your help if you can help me.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000)  means after 1 second later it will be finished. Seems like you have mistake on (1000, 1000)

Comment: thanks problem is solved :)